# Elasticsearch script query started to fail suddenly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-7

We have had this query for a long time

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
   "match_all": {}
  },
  "version": false,
  "seq_no_primary_term": false,
  
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "source": "(doc[params.f].size() != 0) ? (params.m['' + doc[params.f].value] ?: params.o): params.o",
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "f": "scoreSerial",
            "m": {
              "0": "UNDEFINED",
              "1": "FRUSTRATED",
              "2": "TOLERATED",
              "3": "SATISFIED"
            },
            "o": "ZZZZZ"
          }
        },
        "type": "string",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This suddenly stopped working with the error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "bootstrap_method_error",
        "reason" : "bootstrap_method_error: CallSite bootstrap method initialization exception"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "visit-global-standard-w2022.31",
        "node" : "olbLlZh7RYuwaf5S-B9v8g",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "(doc[params.f].size() != 0) ? (params.m['' + doc[params.f].value] ?: params.o): params.o",
            "                                                          ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "(doc[params.f].size() != 0) ? (params.m['' + doc[params.f].value] ?: params.o): params.o",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 58,
            "start" : 0,
            "end" : 88
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "bootstrap_method_error",
            "reason" : "bootstrap_method_error: CallSite bootstrap method initialization exception"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "bootstrap_method_error",
      "reason" : "bootstrap_method_error: CallSite bootstrap method initialization exception"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The mapping of scoreSerial is

```
 "scoreSerial" : {
        "type" : "long"
 }
```

It was working for more than 3 years. We are now on the 7.10 (for more than 6 months, when the above script was working) ES version. But suddenly it started to fail.
The strange thing is that it is not happening in all environments. Is it some java version related or something else? We can not also reproduce this locally.

Comment: I was going to ask whether ALL documents have a `scoreSerial` field with a non-null value, but if you have `doc[params.f].size() != 0` you should be protected. Can you replace `'' + doc[params.f].value` by `doc[params.f].value.toString()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, we have non-null value for all fo them. We tried various things along with `.toString()` and it works. We are not sure why suddenly this query started to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have to do with type coercion, I've seen [similar problems](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18566) in the past (although not with painless but groovy), so simply replacing

```
'' + doc[params.f].value
```

by

```
doc[params.f].value.toString()
```

might do the trick

(i.e. explicitly getting the string version of the doc value instead of relying on type coercion). What you did [should work according to the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.4/painless-operators-reference.html#string-concatenation-operator), though.